# moodle: how to save floating point score results instead of integer resaults in SCORM module?

Tags: flash, moodle, scorm

After giving a multiple choices in moodle (scorm module) floating point results are saved as rounded integer in database. For example 48.66666666% is saved as 49%. 
I checked DB column, **It's a long text**.  How can I save values like 48.66666666 as 48.66?
**Update:**
It seems quiz flash file sends the exam result as rounded integer. So created scorm has a problem. **Please let me know if how can I change the exam to send result unchanged.** 
I use **Wondershare Quiz Creator** to create scorm exams.

Comment: Which version of Moodle are you using?

Comment: 1.9.3. I checked the script, It seems quiz flash file sends the exam result as rounded integer, So I update My question.